# Java Swing text field issue

Tags: java, swing

[click for pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffdgh.png) 
[image]

So im trying to make the same 0 and 1 field as in the red circle. The field shows the binary value of what is inputed into the text field , then outputs what was calculated. So this is how it would follow. User types in 1 so the first zero turns in to a one in the binary field , the user then presses plus and one again but the binary field does not change until the user presses equal . The binary field changes to 10. Does anyone have any ideas as to how i would go about this?

Comment: Some `JLabel`s, a `GridLayout` and probably a `Map` of some kind

Comment: One of the first things that jumps out of me is, don't worry about the UI, figure out how you're going to generate the output (taking a number and converting it to binary and hex).  Once you have this figured out, wrap it up in a simple model, which you can re-use and apply it to what ever output you want